# Writing .htaccess mod rewrite for hierarchical categories

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

i need to rewrite urls for my classified ads directory

i have 4 types of links

**/City**  ==> display all ads in city

**/City/Cat1** ==> display all ads in city + category

**/City/Cat1/Cat2** ==> display add ads in city + category 1 + category 2

**/City/Cat1/Cat2/Ad-id** ==> display the ad itself and pass cat1 cat2 and city variables

original hidden url should be **index.php?city=alexandria&cat1=cars&cat2=bikes&adid=EWSw22d**

Can you please help me  **writing .htaccess** for this structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably replace the first rewrite rule for a rewritecond, but this is the idea:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.php index.php [NE,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)(?:/(.*?)(?:/(.*?)(?:/(.*))?)?)?$ index.php?city=$1&cat1=$2&cat2=$3&adid=$4
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd make it with single rule to revert all unexisting requests to the index PHP and then parse the request string there. Smth like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1 [QSA,L]
```